# How to ensure incoming request in a spring boot rest API is coming from mulesoft?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mulesoft

I have a spring boot rest API  The requirement is that the incoming request should come from mulesoft and no other client. What is the best way to validate this ?

Comment: If you can modify both application, best way to do it is to pass a `custom header` from `mule` and check in `spring boot` if that **header is present**.  However, if any other application  that will also send this header may able to access your spring boot.

Comment: Asking for a best way tends to get opinion-based answers. Usually it is not possible to know what is 'best' for your particular context.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you really need is to have the client application to authenticate itself to the Spring Boot application. You should really use a standard HTTP authentication method, supported by all parties, like HTTP Basic authentication or OAuth 2. Don't try to create some custom authentication method. That will create an unmaintainable mess.